# Override values of javascript objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 javascript objects. The first is the default object, and the second is the override for the first.

Object 1:

```
export const messages = {
'id': 'id',
'category': 'category',
'country': 'country',
'continent': 'continent',
'city': 'city',
'field': 'field',
'price': 'price',
'name': 'name',
```

};

Object 2:

```
window.messages['id'] = 'id';
window.messages['category'] = 'section';
window.messages['country'] = 'country';
```

This seems stupid but there is a reason to this ridiculousness

I am wondering if there is a way for me to override object 1 with object 2 without crushing over object 1. These are both external files.

I apologize for my bad spelling and description

Thank you ahead of time

Comment: What does this have to do with react?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't it be? I assume you mean you want to move the values from object 2 into the corresponding keys of object 1, right? [there's a specific object method that does exactly that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor).

Comment: it's a force of habbit I am sorry. I've been working with react fo a while I type it at the end of stuff

Comment: yes I do want to move the elements but more in a read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need to merge object2 into object1 in some easy way.

```
let obj1 = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: 'value3'
}

let obj2 = {
  key1: 'anotherValue1',
  key2: 'anotherValue2'
}

let mergedObjVariant1 = Object.assign(obj1, obj2); // variant#1
let mergedObjVariant2 = {...obj1, ...obj2};        // variant#2
```

As a result in both variants you will have:

```
{ key1: 'anotherValue1', key2: 'anotherValue2', key3: 'value3' }
```

Comment: I'd note that variant 1 will mutate `obj1`, but variant 2 will produce a new object and leave both `obj1` and `obj2` the same.

Comment: the values are being read from an external file so it's not an issue, is there a way to make this dynamic because I will have no idea which values are being mutated I just know that obj1 contains the elements in obj2